# Database cardinality and efficiency

Tags: sql-server

If I have an "off the shelf application" set up in an organisation that has a SQL Server backend database and I wish to check the entire efficiency of the database - that is I wish to check how good the following are in the database;

1. cardinality and normalisation
2. Indexing
3. Redundant data etc

Is there any software tools that will analyse the database and show any flaws and inefficiencies and duplicate records?

Comment: As per my limited knowledge,there is no such tool to find all three points.Correct order of point should be Redundant data etc ,cardinality and normalisation,Indexing.start reading them one by one.

Comment: @KumarHarsh thanks.  Yes, I have been searching.  There are Database Performance Analysers but can't find anything so far that can actually highlights issues with cardinality

Comment: IMO,there is no tool for cardinality, normalisation,redundant data.